# Let $R$ be a ring with identity such that it has no zero divisors. If every subring of $R$ is an ideal of $R,$ then prove that $R$ is commutative.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a ring with identity such that it has no zero divisors. If every subring of $R$ is an ideal of $R,$ then prove that $R$ is commutative.

This means, that $R$ is an integral domain.

By ideal, I think they mean a two-sided ideal. Now, a subring of a ring is a non-empty subset of a ring that forms a ring under the same operations of addition and multiplication as defined for the original ring.

My definition of a two-sided ideal is:

A non-empty subset $I$ of a ring is called an ideal of $R$ if :

- $I$ forms a subgroup of $R$ under addition,
- For every, $r\in R$ and $u\in I$ we have $ru,ur\in I.$

But unfortunately, I can't think of a way to solve this problem. Any help regarding thus will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Consider the subring generated by $\{n\cdot1_R | n\in \Bbb{Z}\}$ and use the fact that this is also an ideal

Comment: @SoumikMukherjee Sorry, but I didn't get it. I just can't think of how to use that the set you mention is an ideal.

Comment: In the second bullet of your definition of ideal, you refer to membership in $U$ [which hasnot been defined], where I think you mean membership in $I.$

Comment: @Thomas Consider any arbitrary element $r$. Now $r\cdot1_R$ is in the subring. Can you do it from here?

Comment: @coffeemath Yes, thanks for pointing out the typo. I have fixed it. Any idea on how to solve the problem?

Comment: @SoumikMukherjee Oh! I think I got it. My solution is: If $r\in R$ then $r.1_R\in$ the subring you mention(say we call it $S$) as the subring is an ideal. This means, $R\subseteq S$ and thus all elements of $R$ can be written as a finite sum of sum of $1_R$'s or $-1_R$'s. Let $x,y\in R$ then, $\exists m,n\in\Bbb Z$ such that $x=m1_R$ and $y=n1_R$. We note that, $xy=(m1_R)(n1_R)=(mn)1_R=(nm)1_R=(n1_R)(m1_R)=yx.$ Since, $x,y\in R$ are arbitrary so, $xy=yx,\forall x,y\in R$ due to which, $R$ is commutative. Did I get it?

Comment: That's a very weird question. If by subring you mean that it must contain the identity (which is the usual definition) then it can only be an ideal if it is equal to the whole ring $R$. So you basically assume that there are no proper subrings. But then clearly $R=\mathbb{Z}\cdot 1_R$.

Comment: Whether or not subrings have to contain identity is not nearly as odd as the fact the "no zero divisors" hypothesis seems totally irrelevant.

Comment: @Mark I think the question has some typo. It does make sense if we don't require $R$ to have an identity. (See my answer).

Comment: @rschwieb If you try to prove the proposition for rings without identity, the fact that $R$ does not have zero divisors is needed. (See my answer)

Comment: @Nothingspecial Looks like this may be the case!

Answer (score 1):

The proof is interesting if you don't require $R$ to have an identity.

Let $R$ be a ring such that it has no zero divisors and every subring of $R$ is an ideal of $R$.  We intend to prove that $R$ is commutative.

Pick a non-zero element $x\in R$ and consider its centralizer $C(x)$ which is a subring and also an ideal.

Pick another non-zero element $r\in R$, we have $rx\in C(x)$ (by definition of ideal).

\begin{align}(xr-rx)x &= xrx-rx^2\\ &= x(rx)-rx^2\\ &= (rx)x-rx^2\\&= 0 \end{align}

Now, $$(xr-rx)x=0\implies xr-rx=0$$  $\because \ R$ does not contain zero divisors and $x\neq 0$ by choice.

Thus, we have $rx=xr$ for all non-zero $r,x\in R$. $\blacksquare$

In case, $R$ has an identity (I believe it's a mistake or typo in your source), the proof is trivial. The centre of the ring $C(R)$ is an ideal and it contains the identity $1_R$. Thus, for every $r\in R$, the product $r\cdot 1_R=r\in C(R)$ and hence, $R\subseteq C(R)$.